# Gitlab CI tries to find 'of:latest' image from public docker hub

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the following .gitlab-ci.yml task for an elixir project:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
    - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release
  - deploy

variables:
  TEMP_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/farmmix/homepage/farmmix_homepage:$CI_COMMIT_SHA

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com 

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd src
    - docker build --pull -t $TEMP_IMAGE .
    - docker push $TEMP_IMAGE

test:
  stage: test
  variables:
    DB_DATABASE: test
    DB_USERNAME: postgres
    DB_PASSWORD: postgres
    DB_URL: postgres
  script:
    - echo $TEMP_IMAGE
    - docker pull $TEMP_IMAGE
    - docker pull postgres:9.5-alpine
    - docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=$DB_DATABASE -e POSTGRES_USER=$DB_USERNAME -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD -d postgres:9.5-alpine
    - docker run --link postgres $TEMP_IMAGE ecto.create ecto.migrate test
```

The `$TEMP_IMAGE` is an existing image that gets created at a previous `build` task.

If I run it locally with `gitlab-runner exec docker --docker-privileged test`, it works fine.

However, gitlab runner gives me the following:

```
... AFTER INITIALIZATION ...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded
$ echo $TEMP_IMAGE 
registry.gitlab.com/farmmix/homepage/farmmix_homepage:b0c30097a320933f7d5390d7037960e34d2ef7d
$ docker pull $TEMP_IMAGE
b0c30097a320933f7d5390d7037960e34d2ef7d0: Pulling from farmmix/homepage/farmmix_homepage
605ce1bd3f31: Pulling fs layer
...
e0c7f5df971a: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:ce7a1bf2378628902e171a22ee386af6c79e8d2340b6241ab70e83173e32ce28
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/farmmix/homepage/farmmix_homepage:b0c30097a320933f7d5390d7037960e34d2ef7d0
$ docker pull postgres:9.5-alpine
9.5-alpine: Pulling from library/postgres
550fe1bea624: Pulling fs layer
04bf519c70df: Pulling fs layer
...
0dca1c6b5036: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:fc3b8fcc8ba568492ce89fd8723a949f586e2919d7884b9b1d8064237ba105d7
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:9.5-alpine
$ docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=$DB_DATABASE -e POSTGRES_USER=$DB_USERNAME -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD -d postgres:9.5-alpine
Unable to find image 'of:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for of, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See 'docker run --help'.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 125
```

I cannot even find anything on the internet of this `'of:latest'` error. I tried running the `docker run` command without the `-e` arguments but the same error appeared so it's not that the env vars are causing any trouble.

I'm running out of ideas. Do any of you guys suspect what the solution might be?

EDIT: Added complete `.gitlab-ci.yml` content

EDIT2: Added `echo` and output of job

Comment: Can you add your entire (or at least the build job) `.gitlab-ci.yml`? Including the defining of `$TEMP_IMAGE`?

Comment: Added the requested parts of the script

Comment: Thanks, can you add a `echo $TEMP_IMAGE` as the first script line in your `test` job? And post all output of that job?

Comment: I added it but as you can see, the issue is already happening with the postgres database, even before the $TEMP_IMAGE would even be started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=$DB_DATABASE -e POSTGRES_USER=$DB_USERNAME -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD -d postgres:9.5-alpine
Unable to find image 'of:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for of, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
```

One of your variables almost certainly contains the string " of " in it. You could test this by adding a line:

```
echo docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=$DB_DATABASE -e POSTGRES_USER=$DB_USERNAME -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD -d postgres:9.5-alpine
```

first to see what it's trying to run. With variables, it's a good practice to quote them to avoid any issues with special characters or spaces:

```
docker run --name postgres -e "POSTGRES_DB=$DB_DATABASE" -e "POSTGRES_USER=$DB_USERNAME" -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD" -d postgres:9.5-alpine
```

Comment: Ah you were right of course! The reason this issue happened in the first place is that even though I set the database variables in `variable`, they got overshadowed by gitlab CI's secret variables because I had them set with different values. One of those values was a text with spaces in it, with the word "of" in it :)